# Using Date fields in process builder as conditions

Tags: formula, process-builder, date, conditional

I am trying to use date fields as part of my condition in a process builder to say:

1. If field #1 (number) has value > 0
2. AND field #2 (date) is less than 30 days ago (ie. date is within the last 30 days)
3. Then update record with X value

Here is how I set it up in the process builder, using formula for the date field where (see screenshot below):

- Date field formula is less than Today() - 30

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTYj3.png

However, this doesn't seem to work when I activate the process builder and test it out. I suspect it has to do with my date field/formula and would like some guidance on how to fix!

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: have you looked at debug log to see what values are being evaluated at run time? Your formula expression looks fine -- but you need to consider how the PB is invoked and configured (on every edit or only when fields meet conditions).

Note also that PB is end-of-life and you should be using Flow

Comment: Thank you for the comment @cropredy - I am trying to look at flow builder instead but it wont let me create the conditions using a formula with a date field. It asks me to enter a fixed date, which won't work since it has to be "less than 30 days from the date input in the date field". Do you know a workaround?

Comment: Also the current PB is set to trigger when record is created and/or updated so it should be triggering appropriately when I activate and edit the said record but it looks like nothing happens. Hence I assumed the date formula was maybe the issue...

Comment: Summer 22 solves the flow entry condition issue (with formula expressions) ..It goes GA this weekend (June 11)

Comment: It did fix it indeed @cropredy thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it seems to work - field name -> less than -> formula -> Today() -7